# Getting data from a site, which cant be found in main HTML file in Python

Tags: python, html

I'am using python and making a request:
`page = requests.get('http://www.finam.ru/profile/moex-akcii/aeroflot/news/?start-date=2016-01-01&end-date=2016-12-31',auth=('user', 'pass'))`

I expect, that i will be able to find everything, that i can see, when i view the website. But as i dont know it for certian and not familiar with libraries, i try to check it manually:

1. I RightClick on the random part of the page and select "show the page code". And actually, i can not find needed info there!
2. I RightClick on the random part of the page and select "research this element", and i CAN find it there in a wierd "tree" structure :
   [image: research this item]

So the question is, which HTML file i recieve, when making request? and how to retrive  topic names from the "tree structure".
Total noob with HTML.

Comment: Look for div's with class "subject". This is what I think you were looking for. If you still don't see it the answer below is the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the source html, there is a JavaScript code running on the web site, which manipulate and change the DOM (the tree structure that you describe). When you request it via Python, the JavaScript code does not run so you can see only the initial html code. Doing such stuff called scraping , you can do it with tools such as selenuim